# Thread local is displaying same data for all instaces of object

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I just sharing my object in its lower modules using thread_local. but its taking last instance object data always.

**code:**

Test1.h

```
class Test2;
extern thread_local void* currentpointer;
class Test1
{
public:
    Test1(int val);
    void display() ;

    Test2 *obj;

private:
    int temp;
};
```

Test1.cpp

```
thread_local void* currentpointer=nullptr;

Test1::Test1(int val)
{
    currentpointer = this;
    obj = new Test2;
    temp = val;
}
void Test1::display()
{
    qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<temp;
}
```

Test2.h

```
class Test2
{
public:
    Test2();
    void display();
};
```

Test2.cpp

```
Test2::Test2()
{
}
void Test2::display()
{
    ((Test1*)currentpointer)->display();
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   Test1 obj1(100);
   Test1 obj2(200);
   Test1 obj3(300);

   obj1.obj->display();
   obj2.obj->display();
   obj3.obj->display();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Response:

void Test1::display() 300

void Test1::display() 300

void Test1::display() 300

what wrong i am doing here could some one help me out of this problem.

Comment: Uhm... you don't have any threads? (Well, 1, the `main()` thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create objects in this order

```
Test1 obj1(100);
Test1 obj2(200);
Test1 obj3(300);
```

`Test1::obj` gets you the `Test2` object ptr of each of your Test1 objects.

```
void Test2::display()
{
    ((Test1*)currentpointer)->display();
}
```

returns the `currentpointer` static variable

and `currentpointer`gets set each time the `Time1` ctor gets called

```
Test1::Test1(int val)
{
    currentpointer = this;
    obj = new Test2;
    temp = val;
}
```

so basically your code works perfect, the static variable logic just makes

```
obj1.obj->display();
obj2.obj->display();
obj3.obj->display();
```

to return the same object and thus display the same string

Comment: thread_local should maintain the thread specific information right. i am expecting it to dispaly 100, 200, 300 but why its displaying 300,300,300

Comment: your objects are all in the same thread, everything else explained above

Comment: @srinivas `thread_local` creates one copy per thread. In your case you only have one thread so you just overwrite the old value with a new one when you call `currentpointer = this;`.